# Can't find preferred app in Ubuntu Store

Tags: software-installation

I can't find any preferred app (such as **IntellijIdea**,**Pycharm**,**vscode**) in Ubuntu store. Also my menu is gone.See the image for more information:

[image: First image]
[image: Second Image]
[image: Third Image]

I can download the applications from internet but I want to download easily from Ubuntu Store.

Comment: Try with snap! `snap find Pycharm`  `sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @koni_raid. It worked perfectly. But my snap store also get fixed automatically after sometime.